# Maximum number of screenshots in 1 sec in iphone

Tags: iphone, screenshot

I wants to know how many screenshot we can take in 1sec in iphone . Currently I am getting 5 screenshots. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(saveImageInPhotoAlbum) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    -(void)saveImageInPhotoAlbum
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height));

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot)];

    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

Comment: you should perform the image conversion in a background thread/queue

Comment: i want to create good quality video so i need at least 15 screenshots  in  1 sec.any suggestion for that?

Comment: i would be helpful to check with method call needs the most time to execute. (e.g with the time instruments time profile.) and i think the image convert is the time eater. so execute this task in a background queue would increase the FPS

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
-(void)saveImageInPhotoAlbum
{
    for (int i=0;i<10,i++)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height));

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot)];

    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
i++;
NSLog(@"Counting of Photos= %d",i);
}
```